# Front End . Современные фреймворки для создания красивых сайтов

Tags: javascript, css, анимация, frontend, framework

Всем привет, подскажите, какие сейчас есть перспективные и востребованные фреймворки js для создания красивых 3д анимаций на сайте, переходов, эффектов? Наподобие таких сайтов:

https://activetheory.net/home

http://launchit.shanemielke.com

http://xmas.evs.com/2018/

Если тут используются не только фреймворки, то что еще нужно для создания таких сайтов ( их front-end части).

Comment: я слышал про такое расширение хрома  как Wappalyzer .Устанавливаешь и видишь какой сайт использует какую технологию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону WebGL фреймворков, коих много:

[three.js](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_postprocessing_advanced)

[babylon.js](https://www.babylonjs.com/)

[pixi.js](https://pixijs.io/examples/#/picture/overlay.js)

Хотя и SVG тоже могут быть очень даже:

[snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/demos/#coffee)

[anime.js](https://animejs.com/)

[green sock](https://greensock.com/examples-showcases)

В целом чтобы рисовать на компьютере надо хотя бы немного знать математику.

Конечно использование фреймворков понижает этот порог, однако я все равно рекомендую больше времени уделять именно [математике](https://betterexplained.com/articles/developing-your-intuition-for-math/).

PS: Надо было сразу это написать. конечно же есть ещё [`d3.js`](https://d3js.org) это не Фреймворк, это набор библиотек, в которых реализовано много разных алгоритмов и структур данных.

Среди прочего есть один модуль d3-selection, который предназначен для манипуляций с узлами DOM и привязки данных к узлам. Концепция, реализованная в этом модуле позволяет создавать, изменять и удалять узлы в зависимости от набора входных данных, описывающих узлы.

[Все это вместе позволяет делать очень интересные визуализации](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock)

Comment: за ссылки SVG  мой плюс и поздравляю тебя с новой круглой репой!

Comment: @Alexandr_TT премного благодарен